# LibGDX - Particle Editor isn't working

Tags: opengl, libgdx

So I launched the particle editor through terminal in ubuntu. It opened, but I couldn't create a new emitter or anything. I checked terminal, and I saw this message among the errors:

> OpenGL 2.0 or higher with the FBO extension is required.

I figured this meant my graphics card didn't support OpenGL 2.0. Here's my OpenGL/Graphic card information:

> OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
>  OpenGL
>   renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
>  OpenGL
>   version string: 1.4 Mesa 9.1.7
>  OpenGL extensions:

So it appears my graphic card uses OpenGL 1.4. I don't know much about graphic cards/hardware in general. Is there any way I can run the Particle Editor with my current graphics card?

Comment: I'm not sure if the particle editor requires opengl2.0 but libgdx currently no longer supports anything under 2.0. Your computer must be ancient if it does not support it however so consider updating your drivers

Comment: Toshiba Satellite A135-S4656. I think its time I get a new laptop.

Comment: Take a older revision of libgdx which still supports opengl 1.x. The current does not support it anymore. See this post http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?paged=2